# In Angular 9,how can we disable /Remove a button if the user comes from the current page to the previous page?

Tags: html, css, angular

There is a "Back"  and "Next" button on the current page say, ABC page.
On click of the "next" button , i will be in a new page say XYZ page which also have a "Back" button.
On click of the back button in the XYZ page, reaching the ABC page, i should not see the "Back" button in the ABC page which is a requirement.
How can i implement this scenario using Angular 9?

Comment: Is XYZ page a child component of ABC page? If so, you can use Input and Output decorators [link](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a service and store the "history", then push when navigation ends and pop when backbutton.

If your service is like

```
export class NavigationService {
  public history: string[] = [];

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        if (this.history[this.history.length - 1] != event.urlAfterRedirects)
          this.history.push(event.urlAfterRedirects);
      }
    });
  }

  back(): void {
    if (this.history.length > 1) {
      const route = this.history.pop();
      this.router.navigate([this.history[this.history.length - 1]]);
    }
  }
}
```

You can has a button in a component that inject in constructor as public the navigation service

```
constructor(public navigationService:NavigationService) {}

<button [disabled]="navigationService.history.length<=1" 
        (click)="navigationService.back()">back</button>
```